# How to inject different Slick datasource for testing with Play controller objects?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have two different kind of `slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database` `val`s

e.g.

```
implicit val db : slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database = ProdDataSource.db
```

and

```
implicit val testdb : slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database = TestDataSource.db
```

only difference is the database they are pointing to. `testdb` points to a test db which all the tests use.

I have parameterized all APIs which accept `(implicit db:Database)`

e.g.

```
def save(emp: Employee)(implicit db : Database): Employee =  db.withSession{implicit session => ...}
```

reason to have `Database` as an `implicit` param so testing becomes easier and tests can pass in test `Database`.

Now when above `save` def is called from a `Play` Controller, it'll have to have an `implicit val db =...` given `play` controllers are `object` what's a better way to make `controllers` parameterized (e.g. if it's a `class` we can pass in a class param) to be able to test controllers properly with appropriate `Database`?

Current controller looks as below, which isn't tastable given `implicit val db` is using prod db. for test need to `inject` `implicit val testdb`.

```
object MyController extends Controller {
  implicit val db = ProdDataSource.db
```

I don't want to use cake pattern which really makes code hard to work and ugly. what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You can see how to use Acolyte to have distinct/isolated Slick `Database` for unit testing: https://github.com/voxolab/speech-recognition-api/blob/master/test/MediaFilesSpec.scala

Comment: you are only having the implicit val in the controller and inject it via implicit method arguments, right? That's not the cake pattern and a perfectly reasonable way to do it. You can occasionally move arguments to classes instead of methods to save some typing.

Comment: @cvogt : I am not talking about `implicit` val passing to a method. I am referring to controller which is an `object`. I can't hard code `implicit val db` into a controller but needs to be passed in, into controller as well to be able to test controller by passing `implicit val testdb`. please let me know if I need to make question more clear

Answer (score 1):

If the controller was a class you could make it an implicit argument, but I doubt that you can tell play to pass the database into the controller as an argument. So either use mixin composition to have different controller instances for test and production. Or use play config to swap out the one provided by Play for both scenarios.